# BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM on an empty sequence

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

How could I write a macro that is like `BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM`, but handles the empty sequence, i.e.

```
#define SEQ (a)(b)
MY_BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(SEQ) // expands to a,b
#define SEQ
MY_BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(SEQ) // expands to nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a solution to this problem proposed [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2047), named add `#define BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM_0`.  It was rejected with the comment "no such thing as an empty sequence", but that seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define `SEQ` as an empty sequence:

```
#define SEQ ()
```

and you can use `BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM` directly.

Works here with Boost 1.47 using G++ 4.7.1 and VC 2010.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my situation, I'm doing something like `BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(TAIL SEQ)`, so the sequence ends up being empty in the null case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
#define PP_SEQ_ENUM(x) BOOST_PP_CAT(PP_SEQ_ENUM_0 x, _END)
#define PP_SEQ_ENUM_0(x) x PP_SEQ_ENUM_1
#define PP_SEQ_ENUM_1(x) , x PP_SEQ_ENUM_2
#define PP_SEQ_ENUM_2(x) , x PP_SEQ_ENUM_1
#define PP_SEQ_ENUM_0_END
#define PP_SEQ_ENUM_1_END
#define PP_SEQ_ENUM_2_END
```

This should work for sequences of any size(even ones greater than 256)